# How to validate the header from incoming service in Spring cloud gateway ? I need to call 2 other REST API calls ( GET/POST) to validate the headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud, gateway

I have to validate the header. For instance the incoming request to the spring cloud gateway is

https://spring-test-gateway.com/cloud/gateway/test/

Header:
auth-token:1241241244

**Requirement:**
Call two REST API

a) One is to get the User roles based on the auth-token (/validate/userroles)

b) Other is to get the user id from the auth-token(/validate/userid)

if the user has send the proper token then we will forward to the right micro service.

Question is how to call the above 2 REST API. We thought of calling the two micro service in custom filters and tried with [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). We are not able to achieve it.

Sorry. if the question is basic. Since [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) is not allowed in spring cloud gateway. might be the configuration is wrong. Any insight of this issue might help us to proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

We have to use the Customized Filter for this. Within the customized filter we can call the above rest service and this can be accomplished.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__developer_guide.html#_writing_custom_gatewayfilter_factories